# What is the logic to find final date considering only chosen day are to be counted in a weekday?

Tags: objective-c, logic

Suppose some task can only be done on Monday , Wednesday, Saturday and Sunday(4 days a week).

If I added the task on date i.e.. 3rd November, Tuesday and mentioned that I will complete the task in 8 days. Considering task beginning day is Tuesday, and Monday has already past so I have left only three days this week, what will be the logic to find that day and date after 8 days(on task completion day).

I need this logic for an Objective C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding of your requirement, I wrote some code in PlayGround with swift. It may help you. (You just need to convert it in Objective-C)

```
let df = NSDateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

let dateToCheck = df.dateFromString("8-11-2015")
let comp = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.Weekday, fromDate: dateToCheck!)

// Monday == 2 , Wednesday == 4, Saturday = 7 and Sunday = 1

switch(comp.weekday) {
case 2,3:
    print("3  Day Left")
case 4,5,6:
    print("2  Day Left")
case 7:
    print("1 Day Left")
case 1:
    print("Last Day Left")
default:
    print("")
}
```

I just used the weekday of date component.

Answer (score 3):

Hi I converted the above code to Objective-C.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
df.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy";
NSDate *dateToCheck = [df dateFromString:@"8-11-2015"];
NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:dateToCheck];

// Monday == 2 , Wednesday == 4, Saturday = 7 and Sunday = 8

if (comp.weekday == 2 || comp.weekday == 3) {
    NSLog(@"3  Day Left");

}else if (comp.weekday == 4 || comp.weekday == 5 || comp.weekday == 6){
    NSLog(@"2  Day Left");

}else if (comp.weekday == 7 || comp.weekday == 1){
    NSLog(@"1  Day Left");

}else if (comp.weekday == 1 ){
    NSLog(@"Last Day Left");

}
```